# PHP/JQuery - Send data to a client from another client

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, chat

I'm building a person to person chat, and want person A's page to refresh, loading new messages from Person B when Person B sends them. How would I send a message/data to Person A when Person B sends a message via PHP? I know I can check on Person A's page via Ajax, but constantly running a MySQL query would drastically bring down the server's speed. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Using Server Sent Events, here's my script code:

```
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("update.php?user=<? echo $recip ?>");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
    document.write(event.data);
    if (event.data=="yes"){
    window.location.href="/chat?with=<? echo $recip ?>";
    }
    };
} else {
    document.getElementById('info-text').innerHTML="Hmm... looks like your browser doesn't support auto updating. Please refresh the page to check for new messages." //'
}
```

And here's my PHP code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
$user=$_GET['user'];
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chatmsg WHERE sender='$myusername' AND receiver='$recip' OR sender='$recip' AND receiver='$myusername'");
$newrows=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($newrows!=$_SESSION['chat'.$user]) {
echo "data: yes";
flush();
}
else {
echo "data: no";
flush();
```

The problem is, nothing is happening when there's a new row in MySQL.

Comment: I think what you are wanting to use is a websocket. I have personally never tried using one, and I don't really know how it works, but I know this is what you would use a websocket for.

Comment: Could you give some instructions/information as an answer?

Comment: I really can't. Here is a link I am hoping to one day try out, which may or may not be of value to you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, everyone. I still used the Server Sent Events, but made some changes and found the error. Here's the final working code:

PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$user=$_GET['user'];
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chatmsg WHERE sender='$myusername' AND receiver='$user' OR sender='$user' AND receiver='$myusername'");
$newrows=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($newrows!==$_SESSION['chat'.$user]) {
  $msg="yes";
}
else {
  $msg="no";
}  
echo "data: {$msg}\n\n";
flush();
sleep(10);
```

(sleep is to save server resources).

JS:

```
var source = new EventSource('update.php?user=<? echo $recip ?>');
source.onmessage = function(e) {
  if (e.data=="yes") {
    window.location.href="viewchat.php?viewer=<? echo $viewer ?>&recip=<? echo $recip ?>";
  }
}
```